# C# Code First: Does the foreign key automatically update when property is changed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using the first code approach to entity framework for the first time and I have managed to create all the entities and successfully generate a database from them. I had a look at a few questions on here to do so and I noticed that no one has written code that updates the foreign key if the property has changed.

This is some code from one of my entities:

```
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    private int CompanyId;

    public virtual Company Company
    {
        get
        {
            return Company;
        }
        set
        {
            Company = value;
            CompanyId = value.Id; //is this needed?
        }
    }
```

So my question is: do I need to manually set the CompanyId when the Company property is changed, like I have in the code above? Or does this happen automatically?

Hope the question is clear enough. Thanks in advance
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly setting the foreign-key property is not needed and will be done automatically upon calling `SaveChanges()`.

However, if for some reason you need the foreign-key property to be updated before calling `SaveChanges()` you may want to do it manually.

Also, when setting a new/detached `Company` (which usually doesn't have an `Id` set yet), the `CompanyId` property will be updated with the newly-generated-id upon calling `SaveChanges()` as well.

For more information see EF's [Relationships and Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx).